# How to create autostart services in Docker container?

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I wand build Docker image with PHP-FPM and nginx inside.
Try use ENTRYPOINT for execute

```
service php-fpm start
service nginx start
```

But see "entrypoint.sh: permition denied".
Help me fix it problem, please, or propose any way to start services on the container start.

Comment: Could it just be a permission issue? Try following the instructions here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/409025/permission-denied-when-running-sh-scripts

Comment: yes `chmod +x` solve my problem, but I think exist more elegant way to do that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices to solve that:

1. Edit the permissions of the `entrypoint.sh` during building the image using this:

   ```
   RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh
   ```

OR,

2. You can execute your entrypoint.sh like this:

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "/entrypoint.sh"
   ```

The last choice will just execute the script **without** `x` permissions.

Both of them will be well for you. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it works, but i think exist more elegant way to do what i want

Comment: I don't think so, at least, you may already have the script inside your image (you coppied it and then commited the container), and before that you gave the proper permissions.

Comment: Just edit the permission of the entrypoint, or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean start services without using entrypoint and editing local.rc file

Comment: Would you edit your run command? if you don't mind editing your docker run ..... command (when creating and starting the container), then I will add another answer